# mysql order by 1+ and append 0 to the end

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how to order by 1+ and then anything with a 0 value at the end.

SQL Structure:

```
id || show_title || season || episode || title || plot || runtime || airdate
```

I want to order by `show_title`,`season`,`episode(1+)` then any episodes with a 0 value for `episode` after the others.

Comment: with as many answers that all LOOK like they would work, and no "Accepted Answer" indicated, are they correct or not.  if not, could you dump some sample data and how you EXPECT the results.

Comment: Sorry had to go in to work for a minute after i posted that. answer approved now! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply

```
SELECT 
......
ORDER BY show_title ASC, seasons ASC, (episode>0) DESC, episode ASC
```

**edit** cleaned this up after checking Marc B's

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT ...
...
ORDER BY show_title, season, (episode = 0) DESC, episode
```

in short, the `episode = 0` will evaluate to a boolean true/false. Order by `DESC` makes any true results (episode really does = 0) come out first, then order by all the other episode values afterwards in ascending (default) order.

Comment: Beaten to it - this one is slightly cleaner + has a nice explanation though

Comment: @MarcB, I think it should be `(episode > 0)` so that episode's = 0 come after the others.

Comment: I didn't notice that @MGA - I guess my response was the correct one after all! :)

Comment: @Simonatmso.net, I noticed it from the beginning but I thought that I was wrong, these 79.5K reputation makes you totally self-doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

Then you do exactly as you said .. ?

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY show_title, season, episode DESC
```

Note in MySQL the default order is ascending, so I explicitly put the '`DESC`'(ending) in the query to make it order descending.

(Is `episode` a text field containing `1+` or `0`, or is it numeric?)

[MySQL `ORDER BY` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
 SELECT ...
 FROM tablename
 ORDER BY  show_title,season,if(episode=0,1,0)
```